# Android Facebook Like Button In a Dialog Fragment

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-like

Trying to use the current Facebook SDK's Like Button on Android.  Have the button in a Dialog Fragment, it appears fine, but when the button is pressed getting:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ContextThemeWrapper cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
```

This is coming from the Activity = line in the like button code:

```
   private void toggleLike() {
    if (likeActionController != null) {
        Activity activity = (Activity)getContext();
        likeActionController.toggleLike(activity, getAnalyticsParameters());
    }
}
```

It looks like it does not like the fact the the getContext() is not liking the Dialog Fragment?

Comment: you need the context of the activity hosting the fragment

Comment: Ok, but this is in the provided code from Facebook......